# How to persist child entity in SEAM using EnitityHome persist method?

Tags: hibernate, seam

I have two entity with a relationship of one-to-one namely Customer and CustomerDetails mapped on their specific tables.

I have a form in the page that captures each values to the property of each Entity.

How am i going to persist this in SEAM?
since my command button only points to one action method which the CustomerHome.persist()

What i did is to assign the value in my form to the property of CustomerDetails like

```
value="#{customerHome.intance.customerDetails.address}"
```

but i am getting error that customerDetails resolve to null.

another work arround is to have two persist method in my CustomerHome persist method that persist both entities but i am getting another error that the ID of the CustomerDetails must be assign first before call to save.

Is there anyone who can make this things clear to me?
I am completely new SEAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use seam-gen?

Try to look at project generated by seam-gen

They use a "wire" method to initialize relations.

Basically on creating your instance you make sure that all relations point to their respective fooHome.instance objects.

Then in your persist method you call first the persist method of the relation's EntityHome.

Comment: no i did not use seam gen, i manually started the project from Jboss Dev studio. I will try to research on wire that you said. Thank you..^^

Comment: i solve my problem..thanks for your help. its the wire method.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you've copied that code directly from your IDE, then the typo is probably the cause of your problems:

```
value="#{customerHome.intance.customerDetails.address}"
```

should be

```
value="#{customerHome.instance.customerDetails.address}"
```

Comment: actually the problem is i'm getting object resolve to null when i reference to child entity..no typo errors.:)